# xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 15

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am making a program that reads and writes an xml file using element tree in python, this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf_8'?>
<data>
    <Hoidap hoi="bạn tên gì" dap="tôi tên là Tuấn" />
</data>
```

here is my python code:

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf_8')
tree = ET.parse("F:\data.xml", parser=parser)
```

and here is the error message:

```
tree = ET.parse("F:\data.xml", parser=parser)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1202, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 601, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 15
```

I have searched everywhere but there is nothing similar to this, can someone help me, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

`encoding` should be spelled `'UTF-8'`.  If the document's encoding declaration was spelled correctly, `ET.parse('data.xml')` would work since the default parser is `XMLParser()` and would use the document's declaration.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

parser = ET.XMLParser(encoding='UTF-8')
tree = ET.parse("data.xml", parser=parser)
ET.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```xml
<data>
    <Hoidap hoi="bạn tên gì" dap="tôi tên là Tuấn" />
</data>
```

See *Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition), 2.8 Prolog and Document Type Declaration,* [*Encoding Declaration*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EncodingDecl):

> In an encoding declaration, the values " UTF-8 ", " UTF-16 ", " ISO-10646-UCS-2 ", and " ISO-10646-UCS-4 " should be used for the various encodings and transformations of Unicode / ISO/IEC 10646, ....

Comment: thank you very much, it's true that I misspelled it, instead of a hyphens I wrote an underscore